# Simplifying inverse trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry

Given below is the question
$$
\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{x}{1+x}}
$$

I tried to put x as tany, siny, cosy nothing seems to be working.

Looking forward to some quick help , I have an exam tomorrow :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\dfrac x{1+x}}=y\implies-\dfrac\pi2\le y\le\dfrac\pi2\implies\cos y\ge0$

$\implies\sqrt{\dfrac x{1+x}}=\sin y\implies\dfrac x{1+x}=\sin^2y\iff x=\tan^2y$

$\implies\tan y=\sqrt x$ as $\cos y\ge0$

$\implies \sin^{-1}\sqrt{\dfrac x{1+x}}=y=\tan^{-1}\sqrt x$

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

$$\sqrt{\frac{x}{1+x}}=\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{1+x}}$$

Now, use $x=\tan^2\theta~,~\theta\in\left(-\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$

Comment: Nice! Thx a lot

Comment: You can accept it if you want. :)

Comment: Funnily though, this results in $\mathrm{arctan}\sqrt x$. I'd like to ask the questioner what sort of a "simplification" this is...

Comment: @GPerez, Well, size of the expression matters maybe! :P Btw, I noticed that there was another mistake in my answer. I edited it now. :)

Comment: Almost, your interval should be open!

Comment: @GPerez, thanks again. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try drawing a right-angled triangle with the opposite side as $\sqrt{x}$ and hypotenuse as $\sqrt{1+x}$. What is the third side, and how else can you represent the angle?

Comment: But the question says simplify

Comment: @Mohit Bhasi, So if you draw the triangle, it simplifies to $arctan\sqrt{x}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $ Q = \tan ^{2}u \rightarrow  Q =  \pm u $