# Evaluating: $I_1 = \int\sin^{-1} \left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+a}}\;\right) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

$$I_1 =\int \sin^{-1} \left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+a}}\;\right) dx= ?$$

I tried substitution: $\sin^{-1} \left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+a}}\;\right) = \Xi$, but then I'm not able to do anything after the resulting integral.

*Could someone help?* There must be a simple way to solve this...

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1229909/simplifying-inverse-trigonometric-functions

Comment: with substitution $t=\sin^{-1} \left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+a}}\;\right)$ we get $$2a\int\frac{t\sin t\;dt}{\cos^3 t}$$ ... which suggests integrate by parts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Hint.* Assume $a>0,\,x+a>0$. Integrating by parts gives
$$\int \sin^{-1} \left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+a}}\;\right) dx=x\sin^{-1} \left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+a}}\;\right) -\int x\left(  \frac1{2x} \frac{\sqrt{ax}}{x+a}\right)dx \tag1 $$ and the last integral is easy to evaluate
$$\int   \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x+a}\:dx=2\int   \frac{u^2}{u^2+a}\:du\quad (\sqrt{x}=u). \tag2$$ Bringing $(1)$ and $(2)$ together leads to

> $$\int \sin^{-1} \left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+a}}\;\right) dx=x\sin^{-1} \left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+a}}\;\right) -\sqrt{ax}+ a\sqrt{x}\arctan \left( \sqrt{\frac{x}{a}}\right)+C.$$

Comment: Why not instead use parts with $v = x + a$ and $u = \arcsin \sqrt{ \frac{ x}{x+a}}$? This simplifies the last integral tremendously

Answer (score 1):

A classic substitution in cases where $\sqrt\frac{x}{x+a}$ is present is $x = a \tan^2(u)$. Then $dx = 2a \tan(u) \sec^2 (u) du$,

$$\int u (2a \tan(u) \sec^2(u)) du$$

which can be evaluated easily using integration by parts.